Defining a scene property for another scene created through code
I'm trying to define a scene property for another scene, not my active one but for a scene created through code, I have recently learned how to define properties for active scenes but I'm kinda having some difficulties defining one for a scene created through code, I tried googling, checked up the documentation, no luck.
# imports
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator, Scene, UIList
    
import mathutils
from math import radians
    
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, IntProperty

        
# Test Property Group
class BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    custom_1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="My Float")
    custom_2: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Int")

def Settings():
    # create blender unity settings scene (if it doesn't exist)
    if(bpy.data.scenes.get("blenderunity_settings") is None):
    bpy.data.scenes.new(name="blenderunity_settings")
        
    # store settings
    scene_settings = bpy.data.scenes["blenderunity_settings"]
        
    # create a list (issue)(this doesn't work when trying to define a 
    property for a different scene created through code)
    scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats = CollectionProperty(type=BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)
    scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats_index = IntProperty(name = "markexport_detectedMats index")
        
        
    # create a list (this works for my active scene, but I want to create a property for a different scene)
    #---------------------
    bpy.types.Scene.markexport_matsDetected = 
    CollectionProperty(type=BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)
    bpy.types.Scene.markexport_matsDetected_index = IntProperty(name = "markexport_matsDetected index")
        
    item = bpy.context.scene.markexport_matsDetected.add()
    item.custom_1 = 100
    #---------------------


     ## ----------- register & unregister --------------------
def register():
    # class registers
    #bpy.utils.register_class(_CLASS_NAME)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderUnityPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderUnityUIList_DetectedMats)
        
    # get scene
    scene = bpy.context.scene
        
       
    # setup settings scene
    Settings()
        
def unregister():
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(_CLASS_NAME)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderUnityUIList_DetectedMats)
        
    return ""
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # register 
    register()

error:

Blender version 3.6.17, the code def function content does have space but for some reason doesn't after pasting it here

BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup is not defined in the code you share. Please share your code you are having problems with in full. ...or at least an example that runs and has the problem...

I would just see if you are dealing with property groups correctly. See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html There is an example. I doubt there are any problems specific to scenes here.

EDIT: updated, my bad, I didn't include the property group class because the below code is actually working with the property group, I don't think the class has any issues, it's that I'm trying to define this property for another scene created through code and I get this error, P.S: yea I tried googling going through forums but couldn't find anything related to adding a property to a different scene created through code

The error message indicates that the property doesn't get created for the scene in question. No idea what code you run since you have not posted all code that you run. Maybe try assigning some value to the property when you are creating it...

I have actually posted the code that I run? o_o, I'm not including the imports since if there is any error with that, the compiler would throw something like "name ___ is not defined", also I can't assign values if the code line "scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats = CollectionProperty(type=BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)" is throwing the error, so this line is throwing the error, and after that I can't assign any values

Well, I cannot run it. And if I did indentation would be the problem. Anyway, I think this is about assigning a value to the property so it gets created and attached to the specific scene, like in the example in the docs - the last line for testing. I don't think it exists in the scene data-block if it never gets actually used(if you don't assign a value to it) so whatever you do to it you must be doing it before it exists attached to that new scene and that's why the error.

yea I guess I have to include the imports as well since you can't run without defining them all, also indentation is fine in my code but when I paste it here, its all messed up, + I'm kinda new to stackexchange posting

OK, it's a complete mess now. I am not even sure what we are talking about any more. I would take the example from the docs and work from there one step at a time, start with something that works, test at every step. Best advice I can give in this situation. Sorry, don't mean to be rude.

my bad, the code's spacing is now fixed and also I just used an AI and found the solution, you can't directly define properties into a scene instance but you create them globally and add values by accessing the scene

This is not like Reddit. Don’t edit the title of your question as “solved,” rather mark an answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it.

I was trying to define the property directly to a specific scene instance which doesn't work, so the code below was correct, as you have to register properties globally and then you can use them on specific scenes:
scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats = CollectionProperty(type=BlenderUnityTestPropertyGroup)
scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats_index = IntProperty(name = "markexport_detectedMats index")

After defining properties globally, I can now access the scene and make use of the property by adding values to it, and if you delete that scene the values would be lost
# access my scene
scene_settings = bpy.data.scenes["blenderunity_settings"]
    
# add value
item = scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats.add()
item.custom_1 = 100 


